# Wget Download for Multiple Domains and Files

Tags: python, bash, wget

I need to download a list of files from each of the domains listed in another file. I've tried many times but I still failed.

The example list files to download (e.g., file.txt):

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpeg
4.bmp
5.gif
```

The example list of domains (e.g., url.lst):

```
google.com
google.co.in
google.com.br
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Create an array files that contains list of filenames

urls=`cat "url.lst"`
files=`cat "file.txt"`

   for ((file in "${files[@]}" && url in "${urls[@]}"));   do 
        wget "${url}${file}"
   done
```

I want to get it so it generates and runs the following commands:

```
wget google.com/1.jpg
wget google.com/2.jpg
wget google.com/3.jpeg
wget google.com/4.bmp
wget google.com/5.gif
wget google.co.in/1.jpg
wget google.co.in/2.jpg
wget google.co.in/3.jpeg
wget google.co.in/4.bmp
wget google.co.in/5.gif
wget google.com.br/1.jpg
wget google.com.br/2.jpg
wget google.com.br/3.jpeg
wget google.com.br/4.bmp
wget google.com.br/5.gif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few things going on here.  First, your reading the variables isn't creating arrays.  You're getting a string that will be subject to word splitting and globbing and the like.  Second, you will need to do the two file loops separately instead of trying to do it in a single command.

To fix the first part, I'd suggest using `readarray` or `mapfile`, for the second, use nested loops like:

```
readarray -t urls < url.lst
readarray -t files < file.txt

for dom in "${urls[@]}"; do
    for path in "${files[@]}"; do
        wget "$dom/$path"
    done
done
```

or you could replace the outer `for` loop with a `while` loop and skip one of the `readarray`s like

```
readarray -t files < file.txt

while read -r url; do
    for path in "${files[@]}"; do
        wget "$url/$path"
    done
done < url.lst
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried with: 

`$ sh wget-multiurl.sh, but the result are: 
wget-multiurl.sh: 1: wget-multiurl.sh: readarray: not found
wget-multiurl.sh: 2: wget-multiurl.sh: readarray: not found
wget-multiurl.sh: 4: wget-multiurl.sh: Bad substitution`

probably I missed something?

Comment: @ara93 `readarray` is a bash-ism, not necessarily available in `sh`.  You tagged this with `bash` so I assumed that would be OK for you.  If that's not the case let me know, and please fix the tags

Comment: seems like with bash too, still not works. The cursor in command line is freezing, and when I try check with `ls` the target download not appear and with `ps aux | grep wget`, the activity of wget not appear too.

Comment: @ara93 Oops, that's probably right, I had a typo in my `readarray` lines that would have caused it to block reading `stdin`, those lines now have the right redirection so please try it again with that fix